# How to DRY up this psycopg connection pool boilerplate code with a reusable async function or generator?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, generator, contextmanager, psycopg3

I'm using `psycopg` to connect to a PostgreSQL database using a connection pool. It works great, but any function that needs to run SQL in a transaction gets three extra layers of nesting:

`/app/db.py`

```py
from os import getenv
from psycopg_pool import AsyncConnectionPool

pool = AsyncConnectionPool(getenv('POSTGRES_URL'))
```

`/app/foo.py`

```py
from db import pool
from psycopg.rows import dict_row


async def create_foo(**kwargs):
    foo = {}
    async with pool.connection() as conn:
        async with conn.transaction():
            async with conn.cursor(row_factory=dict_row) as cur:
                # use cursor to execute SQL queries
    return foo


async def update_foo(foo_id, **kwargs):
    foo = {}
    async with pool.connection() as conn:
        async with conn.transaction():
            async with conn.cursor(row_factory=dict_row) as cur:
                # use cursor to execute SQL queries
    return foo
```

I wanted to abstract that away into a helper function, so I tried refactoring it:

`/app/db.py`

```py
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from os import getenv
from psycopg_pool import AsyncConnectionPool

pool = AsyncConnectionPool(getenv('POSTGRES_URL'))


@asynccontextmanager
async def get_tx_cursor(**kwargs):
    async with pool.connection() as conn:
        conn.transaction()
        cur = conn.cursor(**kwargs)
        yield cur
```

...and calling it like this:

`/app/foo.py`

```py
from db import get_tx_cursor
from psycopg.rows import dict_row


async def create_foo(**kwargs):
    foo = {}
    async with get_tx_cursor(row_factory=dict_row) as cur:
        # use cursor to execute SQL queries
    return foo
```

...but that resulted in an error:

```
TypeError: '_AsyncGeneratorContextManager' object does not support the context manager protocol
```

I also tried variations of the above, like this:

```py
async def get_tx_cursor(**kwargs):
    async with pool.connection() as conn:
        async with conn.transaction():
            async with conn.cursor(**kwargs) as cur:
                yield cur
```

...but got similar results, so it appears using a generator is not possible.

Does anyone know of a clean and simple way to expose the cursor to a calling function, without using another library?

Here are the versions I'm using:

- **python:** 3.11
- **psycopg:** 3.1.8
- **psycopg-pool:** 3.1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any extra helper, you might want to write the `async with` statement in the multiple parameter version - just separate each
expression you put in your three `with` statements in the
same statement, separated by commas.

Note that by using this option, up to Python 3.11 (or maybe 3.10,
I don't recall), you can't really add parentheses to enclose
the three expressions and reformat your code, as the parser would
not be able to distinguish them from a tuple. They'd have to be reformatted by the `\` line continuator escape, or simply kept on
the same line.

But, as even this can be inconvenient boilerplate, the simplest way
to combine various (fixed) context-managers is to create a
context manager as a function, by using the tools provided
in the stdlib's `contextlib` module, as bellow:

```
     
...
import contextlib

@contextlib.AsyncContextManager
async def sql(pool):
    # everything in a single `with` statement:
    async with pool.connection() as conn, conn.transaction(), conn.cursor(row_factory=dict_row) as cur:
        yield (conn, cur)
        

async def create_foo(**kwargs):
    foo = {}
    async with sql(pool) as (conn, cur):
        # code block using the SQL conn and cur objects:
        ...
```

If you have some code where there are optional, or other context managers that could be data driven (for example various files to open simultaneously), them, inside the factored-out context manager, one should use contextlib's `ExitStack` class (or its counterpart `AsyncExitStack`). But that is not your case here.